# How to write a function to convert plain text into clickable links where text contains 5 types of URLs

Tags: php, regex

Here are the types of links that are inside of the text. The links may start with a white space or may also be a part of a longer string for example: sometexthttp://www.domain.extension?parameters

```
1. http://domain.extension?parameter  
2. http://subdomain.domain.extension?parameters
3. https://domain.extension?parameter
4. https://subdomain.domain.extension?parameters
5. www.domain.extension?parameter
```

I wrote the following function which partially works. The first regex finds all the strings containing "www." and adds to them prefix "http://". And the second regex wraps them into "a" tags.

```
function MakeClickableLinks($text) {                         
$text = preg_replace('(((www).([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-=#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?))',   ' http://$1',   $text);                          
$text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-=#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@',     '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">$1</a>',       $text);       

return $text;               
}
```

**This is the test string:**
    $text = 'some-texthttps://www.sdfsd.com  some-texthttp://www.sdfsd.com  http://www.sdfsd.com  https://www.ertert.com sometextwww.ssssss.com   www.hhhh.com  www.hhhh.comsdfsdfs';

**This is current output:**
    some-texthttps:// http://www.sdfsd.com some-texthttp:// 
    http://www.sdfsd.com http:// http://www.sdfsd.com https://
    http://www.ertert.com sometext http://www.ssssss.com http://www.hhhh.com 
    http://www.hhhh.comsdfsdfs

The problem is that the first regex also adds extra "http://" inside of a proper URLs that already start with http:// or https://

```
"http://www.domain.extension" 
gets converted into this:
"http:// http://www.domain.extension"
```

Comment: I think the reason is that you first replace all www.xy.tld links and then replace all http(s)://www.xy.tld links. Did you try switching out those preg_replace calls?

Comment: If you do that, though, you'd naturally have to change the replacement value of the first call to `<a href="http://$1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">http://$1</a>`.

Comment: Case 1. Inverting the regex doesn't work because then the second function will still try to add http:// inside of every string that already starts with http:.Case 2 If the rexex are inverted and replacement values are switched it also doesn't work because then the first regex adds the extra http:// to http(s)// and the second regex wraps and the second regex wraps a defective output of the first regex. What

Comment: Ah, right. Then you might consider to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/523104/1898236) which tackles the same problem.

Comment: Danger danger.  What if `comsdfsdfs` is actually a valid TLD?  What if `sometextwww` is actually a valid hostname within the `ssssss.com` domain? If you can rely on there being a limited set of domains, that would be helpful. But more importantly, I recommend you try to clean up your source data, so that your processing can be made more reliable. As is stands, your regex replacements need to make some big assumptions.

Comment: @ghoti,  Yes, some assumptions have to be made because converting plain text to hyperlinks is almost impossible to do perfectly. For example one can never know where is the end of a URL if the URL is immediately succeeded by a plain text without a white space in between. However in most cases if the URLs are not perfectly converted to links it is not a big deal because we have a plain text to begin with which has no clickable value anyway. So for example 95% conversion success is better than nothing from the point of view of human convenience.

Comment: How much do you want to assume?  We could programatically check for `(com|net|org|int|biz|info)`, and if that's not found, take the first two letters and assume it's an ISO country code, but then we pick **http://www.nic.mu/** when we should see **http://www.nic.museum/**. If you're willing to settle for 95%, then we need a bigger sample set in order to determine how much compromise is required to get 95%.

Comment: Please, submit your code as an answer. I'm not against a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using "negative look behind" qualifier to make sure that the "www" is not preceded with a forward slash "/" solves the problem by excluding all http:// and https:// from having undesired insertions :).

Here is the modified first regex from the original question.

```
((?<![/])((www).([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-=#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?))
```

Here is complete working function using first regex with negative look behind together with second regex suggested by Simo.

```
function MakeClickableLinks($text) {       
$text = preg_replace('@((?<![/])((www\.).([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-=#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?))@',  ' http://$1',  $text);              
$text = preg_replace("/((https?:\/\/)[^\s]+)/",   '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" >$1</a>',  $text);         
return $text;               
}
```

This has been tested with php7 and catches majority of URLs within plain text. Additional improvements could include limiting URL length.

Also it would be a good idea to run the resulting HTML through some XSS cleaning library to remove any potential XSS from the URLs.

Comment: In the second regex, why is `https?:\/\/` in parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

How about just getting everything that starts with www., http:// or https:// until first space?

<strike>Regex Search</strike>

```
(?<link>(www\.|https?://)[^\s]+)
```

Regex Replace

```
<a href='${link}'>${link}</a>
```

This is not perfect, but might help. Also I'm not 100% sure above regex syntax is correct in your case.

EDIT: Couldn't make it work with named groups using www.phpliveregex.com. Here's a solution without them:

```
preg_replace("/((www\.|https?:\/\/)[^\s]+)/", "<a href='$1'>$1</a>", $input_lines);
```

Comment: Hi Simo. What is the purpose of the question mark at the beginning of your regex, it only throws an error that compilation failed because there is nothing to repeat.

Comment: (?<some_name>xxxyyyyzzz) is a named group. You can refer to that name in regex replace with ${some_name}. I'm not sure about its correct syntax with preg_replace.

Comment: Quick googling reveals that older php versions might accept  (?P<some_name>xxxyyyzzz)

Comment: Edited answer not to use named groups.

Comment: Your regex works but does not add http:// at front of those links that only have "www."  Links without http:// prefix will cause some php apps to try to look for internal pages with this title and throw an error as they won't be found. 
This is why my first  regex adds the missing http: prefixes and the second wraps links in tags. However your regex would be a cleaner and simpler substitute for my second regex.